# Invisible JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a little problem.
I had some JComboBox to a JDialog but they won't show up ... Moreover I can select them (see the pic).

[alt text http://grab.by/3RwI](http://grab.by/3RwI)

And here's my code :

```
for(int i = 0; i<11; i++)
    {
        JComboBox jC = new JComboBox(posteList);
        jC.setBounds(300, posY, 100, 20);
        jC.setSelectedIndex(0);
        this.add(jC);
        posY += 30;
    }
```

Have you got an idea to solve this problem ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to call `setBounds()`, you need to use a layout to manage the components positions

Comment: Hum yes but I don't think that's the origin of my problem ... no ?

Comment: The layout of your panel will call setBounds() after you did and displace the components. You HAVE to use a layout.

Comment: Ok, I'm coming from Apple dev and I never use layout, it's quite disturbed. Thanks

Comment: Arguably, layouts are not the best part in Swing but you have to deal with them...

Comment: But I don't understand with when I write : 

JTextField j1L = new JTextField();
j1L.setBounds(10, posY, 100, 20);
this.add(j1L);

It works fine ...

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, when you place your components using setBounds(), they stay there until a relayout is triggered. I guess the combobox behaves differently because it needs to pop out and because it's a composite control (a text field + a button + a list), so it needs its own layout.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `doLayout()` method of your JComboBox after manually setting the bounds.  Then the combo box will appear correctly.  E.g.:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);

String[] items = {"hello","goodbye","etc"};
JComboBox cbox = new JComboBox(items);
panel.add(cbox);
cbox.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);
cbox.doLayout(); // force the JComboBox internals to use your bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for the problem. If you're using a JPanel for the GlassPane, over the glass pane you're using a JInternalFrame. If you try to draw a JFileChooser or JCombobox, sometimes the popups don't roll down(I mean it rolls down but rolls under the JPanel). [Here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=c29b68114364d2ffffffff9688f4a420c407c?) is the bugreport from Oracle:
When my colleague found this bug report my eyes shined up. So I implemented the solution of the bugreport to a JFrame, then the popups worked fine. The steps are as follows:

1. First you need to create a JFrame.
2. Implement the fix(hack) from the bugreport.
3. You have to add the JPanel(GlassPane) to the JFrames rootPane, like: `frame.getRootPane().setGlassPane(panel);`
4. When you add the JComboBox set up this: `comboBox.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(true)`

I hope this is the fix for your problems too. It worked for me.